# Problem with a select SPARQL query on dbpedia

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

At http://dbpedia.org/sparql/ I want to select something like this:
SELECT ?hostCity WHERE { `<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lisbon>   <http://dbpedia.org/property/hostCity>` ?hostCity . }
Do you know, where is a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem:`SELECT ?hostCity WHERE { ?hostCity <http://dbpedia.org/property/hostCity> <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Lisbon . }`